# Javascript Elements Not Found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three textareas that I want to use in a simple math equation but my javascript code isn't finding the elements.

Here's the html:

```
<div id="textarea-container">
    <label>Revenue $ </label>
    <textarea id="textarea-formula-revenue" class="formula" maxlength="5"></textarea>
    <label> - Cost $ </label>
    <textarea id="textarea-formula-cost" class="formula" maxlength="5"></textarea>
    <label> = Profit $ </label>
    <textarea id="textarea-formula-profit" class="formula" maxlength="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
function myFormula() {
    $('.formula').focus(function(event) {

        alert(document.getElementById("textarea-formula-profit").value);

        var r = document.getElementById("textarea-formula-revenue").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("textarea-formula-cost").value;
        var p = r - c;

        document.getElementById("textarea-formula-profit").value = p;

    })
}

$(document).ready(myFormula);
```

The alert actually works but the rest of the code doesn't. I'd appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at the console? Does it show any errors?

Comment: textarea-formula-revenue is written wrong in getElementById('texarea-formula-revenue')..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LehL1pru/1/

Comment: you're mixing `texarea` and `textarea` throughout

Comment: @MikeG: Correcting your initial post without any remark may confuse fellow readers, please leave any remark or accept the answer that helped you in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ted mentioned, you had a couple of typo in your code as long as several issues. I'm not a fan of mixing pure JS and jQuery - if we use the library, what for is document.getElementById used? Better to use jQuery short equivalent.

Secondly, it would be better to use the change() method, not the focus() which is triggered even when you enter the textarea.

I will put my code to analyze:

```
<div id="textarea-container">
   <label>Revenue $ </label>
   <textarea id="textarea-formula-revenue" class="formula" maxlength="5">0</textarea>
   <label> - Cost $ </label>
   <textarea id="texarea-formula-cost" class="formula" maxlength="5">0</textarea>
   <label> =  Profit $ </label>
   <textarea id="textarea-formula-profit" class="formula" maxlength="5">0</textarea>
   </div>
```

JS part:

```
function myFormula(){
var r = 0, c = 0, p = 0;

$('.formula').change(function() {

    r = $("#textarea-formula-revenue").val();
    c = $("#texarea-formula-cost").val();

    p = r - c;
    if (!isNaN(p)) {
        $("#textarea-formula-profit").val(p);
    }

})
}
$(document).ready(myFormula);
```

I think it is also good to check whether the value of a profit is reliable to display, hence the `!isNan(p)` check.

Answer (score 3):

textarea-formula-revenue is written wrong in getElementById('texarea-formula-revenue').. Same goes for textarea-formula-profit. Change both version of texarea-formula-cost since you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems with your code...mostly typos in the ID's. Run the snippet below to see it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.formula').focus(function (event) {
        var r = $("#textarea-formula-revenue").val(),
            c = $("#textarea-formula-cost").val(),
            p = r - c;
        $("#textarea-formula-profit").val(p);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textarea-container">
    <label>Revenue $</label>
    <textarea id="textarea-formula-revenue" class="formula" maxlength="5">10</textarea>
    <label>- Cost $</label>
    <textarea id="textarea-formula-cost" class="formula" maxlength="5">2</textarea>
    <label>= Profit $</label>
    <textarea id="textarea-formula-profit" class="formula" maxlength="5"></textarea>
</div>
```